# Error message after sucsessfully writing as group member

Tags: permissions, user-groups, writing

I am hosting multiple websites from my server. All sites are located in /home/www

Recently I started working on projects with two close friends.
As we all need to access files in this folder, I created a group and added all three users.

The folder has root as owner, and the group I created as group.

When writing to files from my user using WinSCP, the changes are saved, but I still get and error after every save saying "Permission denied".

I am fairly new to linux, so be well aware there may have been something very obvious I've missed.

I have already tried unchecking the "Transfer resuming" in WinSCP preferences, whatever that means.

Edit: Permissions for folder /www is 755

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer!
Wasn't really that hard!

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory) thread helped me set the permissions automatically.

As for the error message. All I did was go to Options -> Preferences -> Transfer and edit the default to ignore permissions error.